# Website DR using Multisite

Tags: multisite

I'm new to Wordpress multisite feature. I have been wondering can this multisite be used to create a Disaster Resovery site for a website?

Say, if I have www.abc.com running from my DC which is built on PhP and Apache Web Server on CentOS and has MySQL as backend database and I need to setup DR for the website if in case my production goes down, Can this multisite be used in anyway?

I guess this question might be too simple or possibly would be closed, but if there is anything that you guys could help, that would be great.

Or you could tell me what is the best way to build a DR for website.

Answer (score 3):

No, if production goes down then there's no way to serve the site, since it's a multisite, and a multisite is still a single install of WordPress.

It's possible that code in the theme may bring down a site inside a multisite without bringing down the entire thing, but any DR site will be running the same code.

Instead, for DR, you will want something on a different server, ideally a different data centre, but that's a subject for a different stack, and out of scope on WordPress SE

Comment: Questions about doing DR across multiple servers, datacentres and so on would be well placed over on serverfault.com